# Substitute for permalloy core for power transformer

Tags: transformer

I want to build an `220AC`/`22AC` transformer to use in PSU for `90W` amplifier. The problem is that I can't find permalloy plates for it. What material would be reasonable substitue for permalloy plates for use in such transformer?

Comment: You could try taking apart another transformer that you don't care about.

Comment: magnetic parts are so expensive unless you buy in volume and 60Hz transformers are significantly more expensive. UNless you specify the operating freq it is difficult to find. Rather than looking for peramlloy plates. look for a Universal SMPS with 220/110AC input and 19~24Vdc regulatored output they exist over a wide range of voltages and power ratings for about %0.25/W like these **http://goo.gl/Qp6so**

Comment: @TonyStewart, a SMPS would generate high frequency noise which may be a problem if the amplifier (or the power supply) is not well shielded.

Comment: Now I'm very curious, why do you want permalloy laminate for your core? Power supply transformers are normally silicon steel or ferrite?

Answer (score 1):

If you want steel plates, try to contact a small transformer industry and buy from them.
I work in an industry like this and several people search for us to buy small quantity of materials because the industries only supply large quantities.